# pdo prepared statement multiple execution?

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement, execute

I'm just getting to implement PDO in my site but I was wondering if it is possible to execute prepared statement multiple times?

```
$SQL = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=? AND users=?");
$SQL -> execute(array($id,$userid));
while($check = $SQL -> fetchObject()){
```

and then I would use a while loop for this SQL

Can I use the same $SQL for another execution within the while loop? So I don't have to type in the prepared statement again?

```
$SQL -> execute(array($id2,$userid2));
while($check2 = $SQL ->fetchObject(){
//while loops for second execution, but I'm not sure how it works cause 
//its using the same $SQL?
    }
    }//this end bracket is for the first while loop
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can reuse the same prepared statement, but not how you have it in the question. What you are trying to do is essentially the same as doing this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$some_number; $i++) {
    echo $i."\n";
    for ($i=0; $i<$some_number; $i++) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

The the second `for` loop moves the same pointer as the original one, so therefore the output from the above would simply be "`0`" indicating that the original `for` loop only happened once.

So in order to get around this, you will need to store the results of the first `execute` into an array and then iterate over it. That way you won't have to worry about any pointers

```
$SQL = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=? AND users=?");
$SQL->execute(array($id,$userid));
$checks = $SQL->fetchAll();
foreach ($checks as $check) {
    $SQL->execute(array($id2,$userid2));
    while ($check2 = $SQL->fetchObject(){
        //while loops for second execution
    }
}
```

This way, you are using exactly the same prepared statement (which is good) and the original `$check` variable is available to be used in the `while` loop.

However, with all that said, I have a strong hunch that you can probably get everything into one single SQL query without the need for looping over it like this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible.  Prepare once, execute as many times as you need to.

Of course, I'm not sure why you're doing a `SELECT` in a loop... that typically doesn't make much sense.

Comment: How would I do to get the database? I'm not sure, I used to work with older methods of mysql_query("SELECT...

Comment: @andrewliu, It isn't clear what you are asking.  Why not select once and loop through the resulting data?  Why would you `SELECT` over and over again?