# prepared statement within for loop only executes once

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

Maybe one of you can jumpstart me here ...

I tried to use a prepared statement to store form values in mySQL database with php. I already have `$stmt1` up and running to store the information of my helpers.

Now I would like to store additional information e.g. the days the helpers are able to help. My understanding was, that I prepare the $stmt2 just once and then use a for loop to find the parameter values and execute the statement a couple times.

Preparing the statement:

```
$stmt2 = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO '.$tbl_pre . $tbl_event .'
                                (helper_ID,
                                day_date,
                                needCabin)
                              VALUES
                                (:helper_ID,
                                :day_date,
                                :needCabin)');
$stmt2->bindParam(':helper_ID', $helperID);
$stmt2->bindParam(':day_date', $day_date);
$stmt2->bindParam(':needCabin', $night_ID);
```

And then getting the ID of the last insert statement just once, since it will be the same for all the coming inserts.

```
$helperID = $dbh->lastInsertId('ID');
```

Now starting with the for loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {

  $insert = false;
  $night_ID = 0;
  $day_date = 0;

  if ($night[$i] != null) {

    $night_ID = 1;
    $day_date = $night[$i];
    $insert = true;


  } elseif ($day[$i] != null){

    $day_date = $day[$i];
    $night_ID = 0;
    $insert = true;

  }

  if ($insert) {

    $stmt2->execute();

  }
}
}
```

But it just stops after the first iteration. If I take the execute statement away, it runs for all three iterations.

What am I missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958849/pdo-prepared-statement-multiple-execution

Comment: @Dave so I need to use the prepared statement without explicit parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code allows the possibility that *neither* case will result in an insert. That is, if neither $day[$i] nor $night[$i] is set.

So test to see if you have some loop iterations passing by without doing an insert:

```
if ($insert) {
    $stmt2->execute();
} else {
    echo "No insert executed for i=$i";
}
```

Also, you should always check both prepare() and execute() for returning **false**, which indicates an error occurred.

You don't have to check if you enable PDO exceptions.

Comment: The else statement was a valid point. It wasn't the problem though :-D But you made me see it. So I give it as the right answer.

The code that I pasted above was actually correct but I had an error finding loop build in, that I omitted above for clarity. But as always, I somehow used $i as a counter for that error loop. So it actually finished my primary for loop within the first iteration.

So thanks for getting me there :-D